# MatLab - structure and field arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure, field

I'm learning MatLab on my own.  I have a question regarding a field example that is used in my textbook.  We define:

```
FallSem.course = char('cs101','phy200','math211');
FallSem.prof = char('Turling','Fiegenbaum','Ramanjuan');
FallSem.score = [80 75 95; 72 75 78; 85 35 66];
```

Is there any command I can type that will display all the contents of `FallSem`?  I know how to access data in the different fieds (for instance, I can type `FallSem.course(1,:)` to get `cs101` to appear), but if I type simply `FallSem` or `FallSem(1)` (`FallSem` is a 1 x 1 structure), all I get is general information about the fields such as:

```
FallSem = 

    course: [3x7 char]
      prof: [3x10 char]
     score: [3x3 double]
```

So if anyone knows any command which will let me display all the data contained, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there's no built-in function in Matlab for displaying structures, but you can use [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13831-structure-display).

Comment: Great.  Thanks!  A bit odd that this isn't included in MatLab in the first place, but oh well.

Comment: MATLAB tends to feel unpolished when working with any data that isn't a matrix of numbers.

Comment: Jeremy - yes, so I'm beginning to notice :)